# Error "Insecure world writable dir /Volumes/BOOTCAMP in path, mode 040777"

Tags: shell, ruby

I tried the answer

```
sudo chmod go-w
```

in my `/Volumes/BOOTCAMP` but I'm still getting the warning

It says

> Insecure world writable dir /Volumes/BOOTCAMP in PATH, mode 040777

And when I `echo $PATH`

I get this:

> `/Users/anthonybrown/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin:/Users/anthonybrown/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin:/Users/anthonybrown/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/Users/anthonybrown/.rvm/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/local/php5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Volumes/BOOTCAMP/opt/nuodb/bin:/usr/local/mongodb/bin`

When I open my `.zshrc` file I don’t see `/Volumes/BOOTCAMP/opt/nuodb`.
I’ve deleted it, any ideas?

Comment: Am I not wording this correctly or is there no answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command:

```
sudo chmod 775 /Volumes/BOOTCAMP
```

As well as the one you did previously:

```
sudo chmod go-w /Volumes/BOOTCAMP
```

You *might* need to add the `-R` (recursive) flag to those commands to ensure all child files and directories beyond `/Volumes/BOOTCAMP` are affected as well. But I don’t feel comfortable recommending you do that right away since I am not familiar with this error in the context of Bootcamp’s needs and setup.

Comment: The issue has been resolved, it had something to do with a NoSQL database I installed. Once I removed the DB the issue went away